# Split command output into lines

Tags: bash, scripting

I have to check the health of the nodes in a Kubernetes cluster, so to do so I use something like this, with its output:

```
$ kubectl get nodes
NAME                                 STATUS    AGE
ci-cluster-1-xpgwg744oc3y-minion-0   Ready     1d
ci-cluster-1-xpgwg744oc3y-minion-1   Ready     1d
ci-cluster-1-xpgwg744oc3y-minion-2   Ready     1d
ci-cluster-1-xpgwg744oc3y-minion-3   Ready     1d
ci-cluster-1-xpgwg744oc3y-minion-4   Ready     1d
```

I need to get the number ready nodes, so all I would need to do is count the number of Ready coincidences vs the number of lines, but while assigning this to a variable it does not keep the end-of-line.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your desired output? Just a number? `kubectl get nodes | grep -c Ready`?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, as simple as capturing it into a variable with quotes:

```
export output=$(kubectl get nodes)
echo "$output"
NAME                                 STATUS    AGE
ci-cluster-1-xpgwg744oc3y-minion-0   Ready     1d
ci-cluster-1-xpgwg744oc3y-minion-1   Ready     1d
ci-cluster-1-xpgwg744oc3y-minion-2   Ready     1d
ci-cluster-1-xpgwg744oc3y-minion-3   Ready     1d
ci-cluster-1-xpgwg744oc3y-minion-4   Ready     1d
```

Comment: You can probably lose the `export` (unless you want an environment variable) and the important quotes are the ones on the second line.